# How to find out the exact time of a tweet?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

When viewing a [tweet on Twitter](https://twitter.com/breakingmoney/status/545510394887147520), it only allows you to see the hour and the min (9:26AM).

Is there a way to find out the exact timestamp of that tweet, in milliseconds?

Comment: @Alex That answer is obsolete.

Comment: True. Well, I think the [API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid) remains your only option then.

Comment: @Alex Is there a way to view the JSON files without being authorised?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using the Twitter API tool. More specifically, their [API Console Tool](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console). Had to authorise my Twitter account, but I got the entire timestamp of the tweet, down to the second!